# (i)python2.7 uses a lot of memory, even after del-ing variables

Tags: python-2.7, memory-management, memory-leaks, ipython

I have experienced this several times, and could not quite debug it. Whenever I load some large data set, taking up several GB's of RAM, process it into some machine learning model (in this particular case a large document list trained into a TFIDF model), directly after loading the data, most of my memory is consumed (in this case 79%), after I trained the TFIDF, a bit more is used (typically 1-2% more).

So I decided to delete the data set (using `del`), as I only need the model. Doing this returns none of the memory, even after calling garbage collection (using `gc.collect()`). Moreover, if I inspect what is in the workspace with whos (I'm using ipython2.7), and delete all the variables one by one, none of the memory is returned. It's only returned when I shutdown the process.

However, when I pickle the TFIDF model, close ipython and restart it, opening the pickle doesn't take as much memory.

Why doesn't (i)python2.7 return the memory after variables are deleted? Why does an ipython process with no variables take 8.9GB of memory?

[image: memory example]

Comment: Are you sure the model isn't keeping a hold of the data?  Deleting doesn't delete the data, it separates the name from the data.  If there are no names pointing to the data, then it is removed from memory.  However, it seems like the data is still assigned another name.  My guess is that the model is doing this.  Maybe check the model API to see if there is some way to remove links to original data.

Comment: @TheBlackCat I get your point, but as the screenshot shows, I have deleted all variables (also the model), and the memory still isn't released. Moreover, if I pickle, restart python and pickle the model again, the memory consumption is insignificant (not even 1GB)

Comment: Have you displayed any of the large objects at any point? IPython keeps a cache of outputs which you can access like `Out[5]`. You can do `%reset out` to clear this, or use `%xdel foo` to remove IPython's stored references to foo.

Comment: Thomas: that seems interesting, I will have a look at it once I loaded the data again. Thanks!

Comment: @ThomasK You are right, thanks! It is the output buffer :(